# cannot install llvm using homebrew on macOS mojave

Tags: homebrew, llvm-clang

### System: macOS mojave 10.14.6

when I use `brew install llvm`, this error appears:

```
Error: cmake: undefined method `on_linux' for #<Class:0x00007f7f744bf6b8>
```

Comment: it's been a while since i've used macOS so firgive me if this is irrelevant to the question because it doesnt use homebrew, but if i remember correctly mac OS has a set of "commmand line tools" that usually come with xcode. you should be able to install these separately by running `xcode-select --install` in a terminal window (might take a little while). i'm also not 100% sure if llvm is included with this but it might be. worst case, you can [remove the tools](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/308943/how-do-i-uninstall-the-command-line-tools-for-xcode#310470) if they dont help

Answer (score 1):

I happened to have a Mojave machine and re-did the installation process myself, and it works fine.

Here is what I did:

- `brew install llvm` (I actually used `brew reinstall llvm`, since it is `reinstall` for me)
- `echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile`, brew version would be on your `PATH`
- `source ~/.bash_profile`, apply the `PATH` change

The full installation log:

```
$ brew reinstall llvm
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/llvm-10.0.0_3.moj
Already downloaded: /Users/rchen/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/6d4c3816f98949b64550d4a36656b2661f8e5aeea36a90abbdbea68c8215b9a2--llvm-10.0.0_3.mojave.bottle.tar.gz
==> Reinstalling llvm
==> Pouring llvm-10.0.0_3.mojave.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
To use the bundled libc++ please add the following LDFLAGS:
  LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib"

llvm is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because macOS already provides this software and installing another version in
parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.

If you need to have llvm first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH"' >> /Users/rchen/.bash_profile

For compilers to find llvm you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include"

==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/10.0.0_3: 7,055 files, 1GB
```

test log (after `PATH` change):

```
$ clang --version
clang version 10.0.0
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin
```